# Solving mulitple nonlinear equations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Hi I am very new to MATLAB. I was trying to solve these equations to either get an analytical solution or solve them numerically. For the analytical solution, I get the following error:

Warning: Cannot solve symbolically. Returning a numeric approximation instead.

> In solve (line 305)

Here is my code:

```
syms A B Ph Pl

delta = 0.1;
mu = 0.02;
sigma = 0.2;
w = 1;
k = 3;
l = 2;

beta = (0.5 - mu/sigma^2) + ((mu/sigma^2 - 0.5)^2 + 2*delta/sigma^2)^0.5;
alpha = -((0.5 - mu/sigma^2) - ((mu/sigma^2 - 0.5)^2 + 2*delta/sigma^2)^0.5);

eqn1 = (A*(Ph^(-alpha)) + (Ph/delta-mu)) -(B*Ph^beta)-k;
eqn2 = (A*Pl^(-alpha) + Pl/(delta-mu) -w/delta) - B*Pl^beta + l;
eqn3 = -alpha*A*(Ph^(-alpha-1)) + 1/(delta-mu) - (beta*B*Ph^(beta-1));
eqn4 = alpha*A*Pl^(-alpha-1)- (beta*B*Pl^(beta-1));
sol = solve([eqn1==0, eqn2==0, eqn3==0, eqn4==0], [A, B, Ph, Pl]);
```

Comment: Should there be a real-valued analytic solution?

Comment: @David, I can work with the numerical solution for now, but I would like to learn how to compute the analytic solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Matlab is telling you it can't find an analytic solution, but it is definitely finding numerical solutions when I run it, however, they're all complex. Type:

```
sol.A
```

in your command window to see what A looks like, same with B, Ph and Pl.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to see the results.